# Strange result from Summation of numbers in Excel and Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

When sum the following 28 numbers in list A by Excel or Matlab with a 64-bit Windows 10 OS, a strange -7.21645E-16 was obtained. However, the result is supposed to be 0. What is the issue? Thanks for any help.
A = [1  1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   0.2 1   1   -2  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -2  -1  -1  -0.2]

Comment: Floating-point error.

Comment: Which number or numbers cause the floating-point error?

Comment: 0.2 and -0.2....

Comment: How the error occurred exactly? Any explanations?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Comment: Look at [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/

Comment: Thanks very much! That's very useful.

Comment: try `0.1+0.2==0.3` :)